# Trying to store data in a class, returning nil when changing view controllers

Tags: ios, swift, class

Im making an app where a user can select from 3 different arrays, these arrays change the text inside some UI buttons on the next page. I built a rough demo of the app hard coding the arrays to the view controller and not really using a model at all. Now I've taken all of the functionality out of the view controllers and put it inside a separate class `cardDatabase`.

Below is the `cardDatabase` class.

```
class cardDatabase {

public func updateCardSelection(cardSet: Int){
    print("updateCardSelection called")
    switch cardSet {
    case 0:
        selectedCardArray = cardSetOne
        selectedCardNum = 0
    case 1:
        selectedCardArray = cardSetTwo
        selectedCardNum = 1
    case 2:
        selectedCardArray = cardSetThree
        selectedCardNum = 2
    default:
        print("Debug Error - Card set not recognised")
    }
    print(selectedCardNum)
}


public var selectedCardNum: Int!
public var selectedCardArray: Array<String>!

//Create arrays for each card dataset
public let cardSetOne = [
    "Word 1",
    "Word 2",
    "Word 3",
    "Word 4",
    "Word 5",
    "Word 6",
    "Word 7",
    "Word 8",
    "Word 9"
]

public let cardSetTwo = [
    "1",
    "2",
    "3",
    "4",
    "5",
    "6",
    "7",
    "8",
    "9"
]

public let cardSetThree = [
    "a",
    "b",
    "c",
    "d",
    "e",
    "f",
    "g",
    "h",
    "i"
]
```

}

As you can see there are 3 arrays filled with different words, these will be displayed on a further screen. What I am struggling with is getting my database to actually store any data. When I move to the screen displaying the array, I'm not pulling from the database directly, instead I'm sending the information through the segue.

I envisioned the database to function as the app's model, the controllers can pull the information from the model and display it in the view. Instead everytime I push a new view, the values in the database are set to nil making the database effectively useless!

Below I have included the code for the initial view. This is really bugging me because I swear I've used a standalone class in previous apps to store variables and I've never had this problem!

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

var firstLoad = true

class MainMenuVC: UIViewController {

var cardEngine: cardDatabase!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    cardEngine = cardDatabase()

    if firstLoad == true {
        cardEngine.selectedCardArray = cardEngine.cardSetOne
        cardEngine.selectedCardNum = 0
        firstLoad = false
    }

    print("selected cardNum = \(cardEngine.selectedCardNum), sender MainMenuVC")
    cardSelector.selectedSegmentIndex = cardEngine.selectedCardNum

}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "Present Card Selection" {
        let destinationVC = (segue.destination as! CardSelectionVC)
        destinationVC.cardList = cardEngine.selectedCardArray
    }
}



@IBOutlet weak var cardSelector: UISegmentedControl!
@IBAction func cardSetSelected(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
    cardEngine.updateCardSelection(cardSet: sender.selectedSegmentIndex)
}
```

}

Comment: can you clarify where you're trying to access the card database that the values are nil. I'm not sure I fully understand the question. are you pushing views from the MainMenuVC and always using the same `cardEngine` or are you somehow creating new cardDatabases every time? The code you included doesn't show that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create a new instance of cardDatabase every time you load a new view, it will of course set that cardDatabase instance's uninitialized variables (selectedCardNum & selectedCardArray) to nil. Instead you can --
 either convert your cardDatabase to a Singleton class so only once instance is generated and passed around by calling cardDatabase.shared, which will keep the values available(because that instance is retained), like this:

```
class cardDatabase {
     private static var instance : cardDatabase? = nil
     private static var __once: () = {
       instance = cardDatabase()
     }
     class var shared:cardDatabase{
        get{
            _ = cardDatabase.__once
            return instance!
        }
     }
     //Add your vars and functions below
}
```

-- or if you don't care about inheritance, make everything static so you don't need to create any instance of cardDatabase and their values will be retained at class level (cardDatabase.selectedCardArray, cardDatabase.selectedCardNum), like this:

```
class cardDatabase {

  public static func updateCardSelection(cardSet: Int){
      print("updateCardSelection called")
      switch cardSet {
      case 0:
        selectedCardArray = cardSetOne
        selectedCardNum = 0
      case 1:
        selectedCardArray = cardSetTwo
        selectedCardNum = 1
     case 2:
        selectedCardArray = cardSetThree
        selectedCardNum = 2
    default:
     print("Debug Error - Card set not recognised")
   }
   print(selectedCardNum)
 }


 public static var selectedCardNum: Int!
 public static var selectedCardArray: Array<String>!

//Create arrays for each card dataset
 public static let cardSetOne = [
    "Word 1",
    "Word 2",
    "Word 3",
    "Word 4",
    "Word 5",
    "Word 6",
    "Word 7",
    "Word 8",
    "Word 9"
  ]

 public static let cardSetTwo = [
    "1",
    "2",
    "3",
    "4",
    "5",
    "6",
    "7",
    "8",
    "9"
  ]

 public static let cardSetThree = [
    "a",
    "b",
    "c",
    "d",
    "e",
    "f",
    "g",
    "h",
    "i"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked when I added the shared stuff and it all worked. I am sort of confused by doing it this way, to clarify when I set `cardEngine = cardDatabase()` I am creating a completely new instance of the class?

I used a class like this on one of my first apps and I actually declared the class globally `var className: classType!`, and initialized it on the first load `className = classType()`. I've heard so much about global variables being a bad idea, is it bad in this case? This way I wouldn't need to add code into the `cardDatabase` class which I don't really understand? Cheers!

Comment: @Axemasta Yes when you set `cardEngine = cardDatabase()` you are creating a new instance of the class. Its not really about global or local vars. Its more about retaining (or preserving the state of) the instance that you added the values to and passing it around so you can access the values that you set before. The only other way I can think of than the two I mentioned: if your `MainMenuVC` instance is accessible (and state preserved) everywhere you want to access cardDatabase, then you can access its property `cardEngine` and thus its variables.

Comment: Ok thanks that clear it up. I didn't actually realise I was creating new instances hence why I got confused as I hadn't had this error before. I've read up on singleton classes and I now understand why we make them. I actually thought I was creating 1 class to be read by all, not initialising the same class 3 times! Cheers

Comment: @Axemasta Sure. If you find the answer correct, please accept it :)

Comment: didn't realise I could do that :p, I've accepted it now!